# MySQL DISTINCT with codeigniter... Very strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, mysqli

Ok just to keep this simple I need to loop through the `DISTINCT` results of each column in a this table called `PRINTS` Now here is the strange part ...

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('PRINTS.COLOR');
$q = $this->db->get('PRINTS');
return $q->result();
```

Ok `COLOR` is a COL in the table AS IS `SIZE` and `PAPER`  --- Ok get ready because this is where it gets strange...

If I do `$this->db->select('PRINTS.SIZE');` I am able to loop through the `DISTINCT` values for `SIZE` in the table.

**HOWEVER**

If I do `$this->db->select('COLOR');` I get ERROR: A Database Error Occurred / Error Number: 1054 / 
Unknown column `'COLOR' in 'field list'`

Same thing happens for `PAPER` too -- It seems that only `SIZE` works as it should. According to CODEIGNITER DOCS,  I Need to do: `$this->db->select('COLOR, PAPER, SIZE');` But I'm getting an unknown `COL` error. Spelling is correct. Can anyone shed light on this? What is going on? TY

Comment: `COLOR`, is that a reserved word in MySQL?  Hmm, doesn't seem like it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html

Comment: No its not. This is really racking my brain right now.. Approaching an hour of this insanity....

Comment: @RocketHazmat You my friend must be my good luck charm because I just figured out the problem. The CSV file used to create the DB had inserted a space before the COL NAME, which of coarse is not noticeable in PHPmyADMIN. To make it more confusing `SIZE` was inserted without the space (which is why it worked). Color was actually inserted as ` COLOR` and print as ` PRINT` -- Wow that was terrible :/  New problem now.. `DISTINCT` is looping through the result set and repeating values -- ex it should be `SIZE => a,b,c,d`  But instead it is looping 5 times `a,b,c,d,a,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,`

Comment: Wow!  What a silly error.  Glad you got it fixed! :-D

Comment: Yea tell me about ... Some of the hair on my head went gray on this non-sense and I'm too young for that lol. I think the leading cause is that I'm running on empty (been up 23 hours) I built a bot-- Started scraping and wanted to get the data in a DB to build the form out :) super happy now.... You wouldn't happen to know how I can fix my current dilemma would ya? It seems that `DISTINCT` only works right if I only pass one value `SIZE` or `COLOR` -- If i pass both I get repeated strings from the foreach loop...

Comment: `DISTINCT` only shows you distinct rows.  For example, if you had `small,red`, `large,red`, and `small,red` you would get `large,red`, and `small,red` as a result.  `red` is there twice, because the `DISTINCT` is affecting the whole row, not just one field.

Comment: Yeah I know. The values are distinct. But when in the `foreach` they compound on eachother. They kind of bind together --- I found the solution to my problem..   `if ( in_array($filter_result->SIZE, $size) ) {
        continue;
    }
    $size[] = $filter_result->SIZE;
 
    echo $filter_result->SIZE;`  This ensures that the values not compounded on each other. :) So it only shows the distinct values once :) ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want distinct rows of only each type, you must only use those particular columns individually.

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('COLOR');
$q = $this->db->get('PRINTS');
$q_color = $q->result();

$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('SIZE');
$q = $this->db->get('PRINTS');
$q_size = $q->result();

$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('PAPER');
$q = $this->db->get('PRINTS');
$q_paper = $q->result();
```

As @Rocket Hazmat pointed out, if you have any mixed results they will be treated as distinct rows. My suggestion would be to a) create additional tables to hold these values (preferred), or b) to modify the table columns with the distinct values available.

A sample COLORS table would be like:

```
Colors
id    | name
----------------------
1     | red
2     | blue
3     | green
```

Then the query for this is simple to get all the colors available:

```
$q = $this->db->get('COLORS');
```

Since you mentioned this was being imported from a CSV file I would say you could perform the necessary processing after you have imported the CSV to pick up the distinct values, like above, then put them in the COLORS table.

Lastly, I think the best approach is to do some [simple normalization](http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tutorial/Database-normalization-in-MySQL-Four-quick-and-easy-steps) once you get the data in order to better query it, and also improve the performance of your app.

Comment: Hey Sean thanks for your thorough answer .. very informative :)